# Is it possible to change the value of BaseViewID?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, listview

According to this - [http://207.46.16.248/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.baseviewid(office.12).aspx](http://207.46.16.248/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.baseviewid%28office.12%29.aspx) - you can only **get** BaseViewID from a list view.

If you create a new listview through the sharepoint ui it will automatically add up by 1, BUT if you create a new listview programmatically it will take a (from my experience) random *already* existing BaseViewID and give the new view that ID as well.

So my big question is -- *Is it possible to change the value of BaseViewID programmatically?*

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem as well. What I had to do was create a new List Definition and include that in my solution. In the Schema.xml file I just created a new view using the XML. Then you can change the BaseViewId to whatever you want.